# SIP registration api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sip

Does anyone know if any SIP providers provides an API allowing users to register directly from the iPhone application. As a user register with my application, they should be registered with the sip provider(a sip account) as-well. Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a SIP account at a specific provider, *all* standard SIP providers allows you to register via the standard [SIP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol). It is a HTTP like protocol and you can assemble the messages directly. But most likely you will need something like called *SIP client* that creates the messages, handles the call state, etc. There are plenty of open source SIP clients with open APIs out there even for iPhone. One very popular such client is called [pjsip](http://pjsip.org), it might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across a SIP provider that has an API that duplicates a SIP registration. It's actually a bit of a strange request since the purpose of a SIP registration is to let the server know that the SIP client is available and where it can be contacted. If you perform that function outside of SIP can you be sure that the SIP client is available? And if so will you always know what address it can be contacted on especially considering that contact addresses used in SIP often get mangled due to NAT?

What a lot of providers do offer is the ability to set up static SIP URI forwards, for example you could set a rule that states all incoming calls should be forwarded to SIP URI sip:me@somewhere.com. Setting up that kind of rule can remove the need to register in a lot of cases since the provider will now always forward calls to that SIP URI irrespective of whether any devices are registered on the account or not.

Comment: its just that i have a SIP client, where users have to enter their SIP account information. In this case the user has to register for a SIP account on their own. What i need is that, when a user registers with my application, that same registration details will be sent to a SIP provider and an account will be created automatically..

Comment: And is your client then going to listen for incoming SIP requests from the SIP provider? It's relatively easy to send a dummy SIP REGISTER request to create a binding in the provider's SIP registrar. It's a lot more difficult to process incoming call requests that will arrive from the SIP provider.

Comment: i'm able make call and accept incomming call through my SIP client. I want to make things easier for the users.

Comment: Ah ok I understand now. When you say register you mean create a new SIP account.The confusion arises because register is a special type of request and function in SIP and that's what I thought you were referring to. I know of one service that has an REST API that can create new SIP accounts, mine ;-), sipsorcery.com, however you do need to purchase an account before you can use the API or SIP service.